# API to get the History/ Patch Set details using GerritAPIs

Tags: python, gerrit

Developing a python script to pull the gerrit commit details using GerritRestAPI (rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://gerrit.teamccp.com/', auth=auth))

Able to fetch details such as the owner details/changeID/status etc

Now my requirement is to get the "History" or the "Patch Set details" of a gerrit commit. Attached the below screen shot as reference.My requirement is to capture these details. If there are any APIs which gives the full patch or history details is also fine, as i can filter the data based on my requirement.
[image]
[image]

Thanks in Advance. Please let me know if any details are required.

Comment: Obtained the REVISIONS details using 

rest.get("/changes/?q="+changeId+"&o=ALL_REVISIONS" ,headers..)
Got of a specific PATCH or revisions 
gerritCommitDetails = rest.get("/changes/111123/revisions/14/review", headers..)

Now i am trying to get details related to the Jenkins trigger URL details under this REVISION or PATCH SET

Example - 
https://jenkins.abc.com/jenkins/job/XYZ-Build/23211/ 
Coverity Builds Status : 
  Coverity Defects: https://jenkins.abc.com/jenkins/job/XYZ-Build/23211/artifact/build-images/coverity_dir/html/cov-defects.html
Can anyone share details on this req.